# SQL Query works in SSMS but not in C#: SELECT denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqldatareader

To begin with: It is not a particular statement that does not work. `SELECT * FROM [TABLE];` does not work either. When I run it in SSMS as user A it works perfectly fine. When I use it in C# like this:

```
string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE];"

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ToString()))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            // work with results
        }
    }
}
```

I log this code block with a try-catch and I get this error message: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TABLE', database 'MyDb', schema 'dbo'.`

Even if I run the program on the server where the db is, I get the same error.

My connection string looks loke this:

```
Data Source=Server\Something;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=DOMAIN\username;Password=verySecurePassword;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

User A has the datareader role on the entire db.

Do you have any idea why this might be? My db admins cannot help me either and it does not appear to be a network issue, as the connection seems to work.

Comment: userA is the same as username ?

Comment: Is the user login part of a SQL Security Database Role under Sql Server management studio? If so, you probably need to modify that role to include SELECT permission for that  database.

Comment: You have db admins and they can't figure it out? That makes me cringe uncontrollably. Plain and simple, the connected user does not have permission to select data from that table.

Comment: I see you are using integrate security. Make sure you are using the same user to connect to SSMS. If you are using the same user there is no reason to have different behaviour on C#

Comment: you are not using UserA in your C# program. User ID=DOMAIN\username does not have select permission on that table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have this in your connection string:

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

This part of the connection string is ignored:

```
User ID=DOMAIN\username;Password=verySecurePassword;
```

Trusted connections and integrated security mean you **always** connect to the server as the account running your program's process. You don't get to specify the password; instead, the program will pass the authentication token issued for the user running the process, and the database will validate against that token.

If you need to use a domain login, you **must** run your program as that user. If you need to use a username/password, you **must** use Sql authentication with a non-domain account defined in Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know what was going on in my brain. Now that you explained it to me, it is really simple. I am sure I used the same code etc. in another project and it worked. Guess my user unknowingly has the permission on the other db. Anyway, there is work to do. Thanks again :)